# Reverse a method?

Tags: java

So I have this method....

```
public static Vector2 cellsToIso(float row, float col) {
    float halfTileWidth = tileWidth *0.5f;
    float halfTileHeight = tileHeight *0.5f;

    float x = (col * halfTileWidth) + (row * halfTileWidth);
    float y = (row * halfTileHeight) - (col * halfTileHeight);

    return  new Vector2(x,y);
}
```

and I want to to the reverse method `isoToCells(float x, float y)`

I tried this, but it doesnt make sense to me

```
 public static Vector2 isoToCell(float x, float y) {
    float halfTileWidth = tileWidth * 0.5f;
    float halfTileHeight = tileHeight * 0.5f;

    float row = (y / halfTileWidth) - (x / halfTileWidth);
    float col = (x / halfTileHeight) + (y / halfTileHeight);

    return  new Vector2(row,col);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why did you try something that doesn't make sense to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float x = (col * halfTileWidth) + (row * halfTileWidth);
float y = (row * halfTileHeight) - (col * halfTileHeight);
```

With this two equation we can write

```
x/halfTileWidth = row + col;
y/halfTileHeight = row - col;
```

So `row` and `column` in terms of `x` and `y`,

```
row = (1.0/2) * (x/halfTileWidth + y/halfTileHeight);
column = (1.0/2) * (x/halfTileWidth - y/halfTileHeight);
```

replace this in the inverse method to get `row` and  `column` back.

```
public static Vector2 isoToCell(float x, float y) {
    float halfTileWidth = tileWidth * 0.5f;
    float halfTileHeight = tileHeight * 0.5f;

    float row = (1.0/2) * (x/halfTileWidth + y/halfTileHeight);
    float col = (1.0/2) * (x/halfTileWidth - y/halfTileHeight);

    return  new Vector2(row,col);
}
```